multiply an object inside another one
I need to multiply one object (hexagons) inside another (as in the photo). So that it is strictly within the boundaries, also so that it is higher in the middle and lower at the edges

I would use an Array modifier followed by a lattice modifier

Hello, would you mind adding a bit more information about what you have tried and where you are stuck ?
